# JavaScript - Initialization of a variable from two literal/variables

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please consider the below cases:

**Case 1:** Initialization of a variable, with a literal and a variable, which I have never declared or initialised before.

```js
var x = 10, i;
```

When, I print the value of `x`, it prints `10`. I am wondering, how is this even syntactically correct? It is something unexpected. Is it a bug?

**Case 2:** Initialization of a variable, with a variable and literal, which I have declared or initialised before.

```js
var i = 10;
var x = i, 10;
```

Then, I tried with the above, thinking that, if **CASE 1** can work, then the above should also work. But, I was surprised, it didn't work. Instead it gave an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

**CASE 3:** Initialization of a variable, with two literals.

```js
var x = 10, 10;
```

I tried with above, but it game me the same error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`. Now I am very confused.

**CASE 4:** Initialization of a variable, with two variables, which I have declared or initialised before.

```js
var i = 10;
var j = 20
var x = i, j;
```

The above case gave me expected results, i.e. `10`.

But, after all the above cases, why even at the first place, JavaScript is syntactically allowing to do like that? That too, with a variable, which I have never declared before? I am very much confused. Is there something wrong, like a bug? Or is there any explanation for this?

**Note:**

1. All the above cases are tried in Chrome's console, as well as in VS Code also.
2. Results are same, when I tried with TypeScript.

Comment: Side note: `10` isn't a constant, it's a *literal*. (Granted, literals have constant values...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, considered.

Comment: Try case 4 with `let`

Comment: @Dexygen, it gives an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'j' has already been declared`. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion stems from a misunderstanding:

> **Case 1**: Initialization of a variable, with a constant and a variable, which I have never declared or initialised before.
>
> ```
> var x = 10, i;
> ```

That isn't what that code does. In a `var` statement, the comma isn't the comma operator,¹ it's a separator between variables you're declaring. Your code there is **exactly** equivalent to:

```
var x = 10;
var i;
```

> **Case 2**...
>
> **Case 3**...

Case 2 and Case 3 give you an error because `10` isn't a valid variable name, but that's what the `var` statement expects after a comma.

> **CASE 4**: Initialization of a variable, with two variables, which I have declared or initialised before.
>
> ```
> var i = 10;
> var j = 20
> var x = i, j;
> ```
>
> The above case gave me expected results, i.e. 10.

...but not for the reason you think. The reason that works is that you're allowed to redeclare variables with `var` as many times as you like. The code above is exactly equivalent to:

```
var i = 10;
var j = 20
var x = i;
var j;
```

The redeclaration of `j` has no effect, it's just completely ignored. (That wouldn't be true with the newer `let` or `const`, they give you a declaration error if you try to redeclare a variable.)

**If** `var x = i, j` were using the comma operator, the expected result would be that `x` had `20`, not `10` (see below for details).

---

¹ *"...isn't the comma operator..."* In expressions, `,` is an operator in JavaScript, but unless you group things together with `()` that isn't what `,` means in variable declarations (or array or object literals, function parameter lists, or function argument lists). But just for completeness:

```
var a;
a = 1, 3;
```

...uses the comma operator, which is one of JavaScript's odder operators: It evaluates its left-hand operand, throws away the result value, and then evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that result value as its result. So with the above, `a` is initialized with the value `3`. The left-hand operand in a comma operator expression is only useful for side-effects. (In general, using the comma operator tends to lead to unclear code, so it's best avoided.)

Comment: When I try with `let`, it gives me an error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'j' has already been declared`, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ngShravil.py - Yup, exactly. *("That wouldn't be true with the newer `let` or `const`, they give you a declaration error if you try to redeclare a variable.")*

Comment: This is a solid answer. Now all my doubts related to this have disappeared. Thanks a lot!